# Google Calendar menu - override/modify pop-up event form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Is it possible to add new menu item among Event,Task,Reminder?
Or maybe it is possible to add new fields to fill below in that menu?

I've tried to use apps script but no success for now - it generates a side panel

[that menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0WzK.png)

[compare to this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMTFX.png)

Comment: I think the answer is in related questions

Comment: Didn't find anything related..

Comment: You wished to add an item to an existing menu right? It's the top one.

Comment: So, 9 years ago it was not possible. Probably smth changed?